# How to sort record filter by specific column?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this code that filters my records, it contains 3 columns, is it possible to have it sort by Largest to Smaller for column: [Amount]?

I used `Me.OrderBy` but it doesn't do anything, still shows te record in normal order.

```
Me.Filter = ""
Me.FilterOn = False
Me.ItemsQuerySubform.Form.RecordSource = _
    "SELECT * FROM ItemsQuery WHERE ItemCode LIKE 'B*'"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Comment: What did you try with the `orderby`  `me.orderby = "Amount"`  Did you add `me.orderbyon=true` as well?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Hi, yes I have: Me.OrderBy = "Amount ASC"
    Me.OrderByOn = True

Comment: If code is behind parent form, `Me.OrderBy` would apply to parent form, not subform. Do you also expect `Me.Filter` to affect filter of subform?

Comment: @June7 Actually just the subforum, yeah. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are setting the `.RecordSource` of the subform using a SQL statement, this can be modified to include `ORDER BY`:

```
Me.ItemsQuerySubform.Form.RecordSource = _
    "SELECT * FROM ItemsQuery WHERE ItemCode LIKE 'B*' ORDER BY [Amount] DESC;"
```

Note that you need to use `DESC` to get the largest value first, decreasing to the smallest.